# Call an ASP.net Event Handler on Ext.Net Button Click

Tags: c#, asp.net, ext.net

**Markup**

```
<ext:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Icon="ShapeSquare" Text="Submit" OnClick="GreetingBtn_Click" >
</ext:Button>
```

**Codebehind**

```
public void GreetingBtn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Response.Redirect("www.google.lk");
}
```

In this scenario, I would like to be able to execute the ASP.net event handler on the Ext.net button click. How to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [examples](http://examples.ext.net/#/Events/DirectEvents/Overview/):

Markup

```
<ext:Button 
      ID="Button1" 
      runat="server" 
      Text="Click Me" 
      OnDirectClick="ButtonClick" />
```

Code behind

```
protected void ButtonClick(object sender, DirectEventArgs e)
{
   Response.Redirect("www.google.lk");
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between onClick and OnDirectClick?

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple issues with your original code sample:

1. The `EventArgs` parameter in your `ButtonClick` Method should be `DirectEventArgs`.
2. The `OnClick` property configured on the `<ext:Button>` instance should be renamed to `OnDirectClick`.

You can call a server-side Method using either a `DirectEvent` handler, or manually calling a `DirectMethod`. Both function in a similar way by making an AJAX request back to the page.

The following sample demonstrates both the `DirectEvent` and `DirectMethod` options.

**Example**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Ext.Net" Namespace="Ext.Net" TagPrefix="ext" %>

<script runat="server">
    protected void Button1_Click(Object sender, DirectEventArgs e)
    {
        X.Msg.Notify("DirectEvent", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()).Show();
    }

    [DirectMethod]
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        X.Msg.Notify("DirectMethod", "DoSomething was called").Show();
    }
</script>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Ext.NET Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <ext:ResourceManager runat="server" />

        <ext:Button runat="server" Text="DirectEvent">
            <DirectEvents>
                <Click OnEvent="Button1_Click" />
            </DirectEvents>
        </ext:Button>

        <ext:Button runat="server" Text="DirectMethod">
            <Listeners>
                <Click Handler="Ext.net.DirectMethods.DoSomething();" />
            </Listeners>
        </ext:Button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Add the property `AutoPostBack="true"` on the Ext.net button.

```
<Buttons>
    <ext:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Icon="ShapeSquare" AutoPostBack="true" Text="Submit" OnClick="GreetingBtn_Click" >
    </ext:Button>
</Buttons>
```